# Clearing vector of vector elements

Tags: c++

I've a piece of code that needs to define `vector` of vectors. I use them in a loop ad populate it each time, the snippet looks like:

```
vector < vector<T> > buckets;

for ( i = 0 -> N) {
  buckets.clear();
  ....
}
```

My question is even after performing `.clear()` operation on `bucket`, on next iteration I see old values being present, is this usual?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show how you "see" those values.

Comment: `for ( i = 0 -> N)` is not valid C++

Comment: you really need to show us the actual code.

Comment: Sorry the complete code is                                                                 vector< vector<T> > buckets;                                                  for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {                                                     buckets.clear();                                                                            for (size_t j = 0; j < M; ++j) {                                                          buckets[i].push_back(data_[j]);                                           }                                                                               } // N < M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clear` may just set the "number of used entries to zero"[1], so the old entries may still be readable in the vector. If you don't use `size()` to get the new size, but some other method, the values are still there.

It is also possible that `clear` does indeed remove the content completely and it no longer is accessible. In which case your program will crash if you try to use some of the content.

[1] Yes, it does "more" than this if you want the details, I'm simplifying it. It will for example call the destructor the elements in the vector, but it's still just a case of "stuff will still be there", just no longer counted as valid.

Comment: I'd prefer "values might be readable" rather than "values are still there".  It's not uncommon for classes to zero out members in the destructor to prevent this.

Comment: How do you even know that any stuff will still be there, zeroed out or not? I can't find anything in the standard that would prevent an implementation from freeing the allocated memory when `clear()` is called. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hmmm. The standard says *nothing* about that though. Strange.

Comment: I take it you are not actually objecting to my answer explaining the original questioners observations, but rather to the exact wording of my answer. I have added another "may" to explain that it's not guaranteed that it does that either.

Comment: yeah... cplusplus.com is not consistent with the standard. I don't know what to believe.

Comment: @us2012: The standard doesn't require a vector to free the memory, but no implementation does, because it's probably just going to have to allocate again in a moment.  If not, nothing is lost by keeping the memory a hair longer.

Comment: Thanks all for replies. Yeah as Mats mentioned, I too read the cplusplus article and was confused. My understanding so far was as clear should destruct elements (vector object in my case), even though memory is not zeroed but when new objects are allocated, chances are their that it will not be completely identical on subsequent allocation. I guess C standard library may be playing the trick, given the process address space remains same, I see the buckets vector array to be always same. A simple fix would is to iterate over the buckets vector and clear the individual vectors (it works fine !).